# How to solve org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I use Spark 2.2.0.

I use Spark to process datasets from S3. It worked fine until I decided to use wildcards in order to read data from sub-folders of the folder `test`.

```
val path = "s3://data/test"
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Test")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", path)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._    
val myData = spark.read.parquet(path + "/*/")
```

I get the following error:

> 17/11/20 18:54:21 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist:
>   hdfs://ip-111-112-11-65.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hdfs/s3/data/test/20171120/*;

I execute the above code with the following command:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 10g
```

What I don't understand is why Spark tries to read from HDFS instead of reading from the provided path. The same piece of code works fine with another path like `s3://data/test2/mytest.parquet`.

Comment: Are you really using `.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", path)` with the same `path` as you use for `spark.read.parquet`?!

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: yes, absolutely, I pass the same variable that has this path.

Comment: Why?! Care to elaborate what you're aiming at?